# How can I keep CMake build artifacts when switching branches?

Tags: c++, git, makefile, cmake

I have been working on LLVM, which uses CMake as a build system. I can create an out-of-source build as follows:

```
mkdir build
cd build
cmake ..
make
```

This works reasonably well when I am working on one branch, since Make can reuse build artifacts.

However, when I switch branches, a `CMakeLists.txt` file may have changed. To be sure I am running the corresponding binary of my current source-code, I run:

```
rm -rf build
mkdir build
cd build
cmake ..
make
```

This is inefficient, because I loose all build artifacts. Ideally, CMake would only rebuild what has changed.

How can I achieve incremental builds using CMake whilst switching branches and also be guaranteed build correctness?

Comment: In my experience cmake handles changes to a CMakeLists.txt file properly as long as you don't have custom build steps that don't track all dependencies.

Comment: @GertWollny Does this work when files that are captured by a glob are added or removed? Wouldn't this require regenerating of Makefiles?

Comment: If you change a CMakeLists.txt, then running `make` should re-run `cmake` first.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I use it and I am happy with it (for simplicity assume that I have 1 `CMakeLists.txt`) in entire repo:

```
/
/src
/src/repo1 (on branch1)
/build
/build/repo1_branch1
/build/repo1_branch2
```

so when I want to generate cmake files from `branch1`

```
cd /src/repo1
git checkout branch1
cd /build/repo1_branch1
cmake /src/repo1
```

for the other branch I'd simple replace two middle lines...

In addition you can make more folders for *Release* and *Debug* configurations etc.

I realize that this way is not ideal but it's clear consistent and could be automatized. So script would get repo name (root folder name), branch name, create a folder in fixed location with name repo_name+branch_name (like /build, or ok /home/user/builds) go there and run cmake.

Comment: Does this require that you have to start each build folder from scratch? What if I am just checking out a branch once to review a PR?

Comment: Yes, this would mean that each build starts from zero. I mean you can always overwrite the files with generation, and then run the "primary" generation again. This will save some time. You could also copy the primary build, run an "intermediate" one and the roll back the primary..